# How to print a value in main function?

Tags: python, list, function, return

My goal is to:

1. take an input (until user enters 0) or quit (if a letter is entered),
2. run a few checks to throw out non-integers,
3. add those values to a list, and
4. then print the sum of list.

I'm trying to capture the boolean value for variable close in main but I'm getting an error.

> Error: "close = addToList() TypeError: addToList() missing 1 required
>   positional argument: 'numberList'."

```
#function to create a list
def createList():
    numberList = []
    return numberList

#function to add integers from user to list
def addToList(numberList):
    stopAdding = False
    close = False
    while stopAdding == False:
        integerInput = input("Please enter a number [1-9] or '0' to stop: ")
        if integerInput.isalpha():
            badInput()
            close = True
            break        
        elif integerInput == '0':
            stopAdding = True       
        else:
            numberList.append(int(integerInput))
    if close == True:
        return close
    else:
        return numberList

#function for when invalid number entered
def badInput():  
    print("Invalid number entered.")


#function to sum the numbers in list
def sumList(numberList):
    sumTotal = 0
    for number in numberList:
        sumTotal = sumTotal + number
    return sumTotal

#function to print the list sum
def printSum(sumTotal):
    print("The sum is: ", sumTotal)


#the main function
def main():
    numberList = createList()
    addToList(numberList)

    sumTotal = sumList(numberList)

    close = addToList()
    if close == True:
        pass
    else:
        printSum(sumTotal)



#call main
main()
```

What would be a better way to exit gracefully if a non-integer was entered? Thanks.

Comment: As the error clearly suggests, `addToList` expects an argument:`def addToList(numberList)`, but you don't provide it: `close = addToList()`

Comment: Also, consider using `if close:` instead of `if close == True:` and `while not stopAdding:` instead of `while stopAdding == False:` as it is suggested in PEP8, and (in a very very minimal way) faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you `main` function to look like this;

```
def main():
    numberList = createList()
    close = addToList(numberList)

    sumTotal = sumList(numberList)

    if not close:
        printSum(sumTotal)
```

Other things you can do to make your code cleaner is to remove the `sumList` function and just use the builtin `sum` function, and remove the `createList` since it really doesn't need to be it's own function. Then your `main` would look like this;

```
def main():
    numberList = []
    close = addToList(numberList)

    if not close:
        printSum(sum(sumTotal))
```

Comment: @Cornel feel free to mark my answer as accepted and upvote it if you feel that it answered your question :)

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my code. Also, what would be the best way to check a string so that only integers are allowed? With regular expressions?

Comment: @Cornel the `isalpha` u're using is good, the opposite of that is `isdigit`

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot your argument in the second call:

```
close = addToList(sumTotal)
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys/gals.

I got rid of my if else at the end of addToList function and returned both close value and numberList value: return (close,numberList)
And then for main use builtin sum function:

```
close, numberList = addToList(numberList)

#the main function
def main():
    numberList = createList()
    close, numberList = addToList(numberList)

    if not close:        
        printSum(sum(numberList))
```

Lastly, for throwing out all non-integer inputs entered, I used:

```
if not stringname.isdigit():
```

Works well now.